# Disable form submit unless checkbox is ticked

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I need to tweak the code for a basic form. I'm not a PHP developer, I'm a graphic designer and I have just basic knowledge of PHP. What I need to do is to disallow this form from sending unless the checkbox is ticked. I found some code on the web, that I think should do the trick, but it needs some changes and I'm not sure which part of code to tweak. I looked into the PHP and I'm aware that there is a good bunch of code that I don't need, I see there is also a JavaScript, I already changed the form layout in HTML and left just what's needed.

Here is how the form looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $youremail = 'somemail@mail.com';
        $fromsubject = 'Request from form';
        $bedrijfsnaam = $_POST['bedrijfsnaam'];
        $naam = $_POST['naam'];
        $mail = $_POST['mail'];
        $adres = $_POST['adres']; 
        $plaatsnaam = $_POST['plaatsnaam']; 
        $postcode = $_POST['postcode']; 
        $branche = $_POST['branche']; 
        $telefoon = $_POST['telefoon']; 
        $message = $_POST['message']; 
    $to = $youremail; 
    $mailsubject = 'Bericht ontvangen van'.$fromsubject.' Actie Pagina';
    $body = $fromsubject.'

    Bedrijfsnaam:  '.$bedrijfsnaam.'
    Naam Contact Persoon:  '.$naam.'
    E-mail: '.$mail.'
    Adres: '.$adres.'
    Plaatsnaam: '.$plaatsnaam.'
    Postcode: '.$postcode.'
    Branche: '.$branche.'
    Telefoonnummer: '.$telefoon.'

    vraag of Wens: '.$message.'

    |---------End Message----------|'; 

        echo "thank you for your request we will contact you asap."; 
                            mail($to, $subject, $body);
    } 
    else
    { 
        echo "Error Please <a href='terms.php'>try again</a>"; 
    }

    /* if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $to = 'somemail@mail.com';
        $subject = 'Bericht ontvangen van'.$fromsubject.' Actie Pagina';
        $body = '';
        unset($_POST['Submit']);
        foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
            $body .= ucfirst($key).": ".$val."\n";
        }
        if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
            echo "Mail sent to ".$to." successfully.";
        } else {
            echo "Mail could not be sent.";
        }
    }*/

?> 

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the HTML and Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP form check box example</title>


<script type = "text/javascript">
//email form validation

function everif(str) {
    var at = "@"
    var punct = "."
    var lat = str.indexOf(at)
    var lstr = str.length
    var lpunct = str.indexOf(punct)

    if (str.indexOf(at) == -1)
    {
        alert("Valid email must be entered")
        return false
    }

    if (str.indexOf(at) == -1 || 
        str.indexOf(at) == 0  ||
        str.indexOf(at) == lstr) {
        alert("Valid email must be entered")
        return false
    }

    if (str.indexOf(punct) == -1 ||
        str.indexOf(punct) == 0  ||
        str.indexOf(punct) == lstr) {
        alert("Valid email must be entered")
        return false
    }

    if (str.indexOf(at,(lat+1)) != -1) {
        alert("Valid email must be entered")
        return false
    }

    if (str.substring(lat-1,lat) == punct ||
        str.substring(lat+1,lat+2) == punct) {
        alert("Valid email must be entered")
        return false
    }

    if (str.indexOf(punct,(lat+2)) == -1) {
        alert("Valid email must be entered")
        return false
    }

    if (str.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
        alert("Valid email must be entered")
        return false
    }
        return true         
}

function evalid() {
    var emailID = document.contact_form.mail

    if (everif(emailID.value) == false) {
        emailID.focus()
        return false
    }

    //empty field validation

var naam = document.contact_form.naam
    if ((naam.value == null) || (naam.value == "")) {
        alert("Fields marqued with * must be entered")
        naam.focus()
        return false
    }

var telefoon = document.contact_form.telefoon       
    if ((telefoon.value == null) || (telefoon.value == "")) {
        alert("Fields marqued with * must be entered")
        telefoon.focus()
        return false
    }

var branche = document.contact_form.branche
if ((branche.value == null) || (branche.value == "")) {
        alert("Fields marqued with * must be entered")
        branche.focus()
        return false
    }

    return true
}
</script>
<style type = "text/css">
    #content {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;      
}

    #button {
        width:100%;
    }       
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id = "content">
   Some terms of trade goes here<br>
   Some terms of trade goes here<br>
   Some terms of trade goes here<br>
   Some terms of trade goes here<br>
   Some terms of trade goes here<br>
   Some terms of trade goes here<br>
   Some terms of trade goes here
</div>

<div id = "button">
    <form name = "contact_form" method = "post" 
      id = "contactform" action = "form2.php" onSubmit = "return evalid()">
    I accept the above terms of trade
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "emailmarketing"
          id = "emailmarketing" value = "emailmarketing" />
        <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Submit">
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I would like to strip the code from any unnecessary lines, I need only the accept checkbox and from what I see there are more things like name, adress etc.. what lines should I leave in the PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit this section of PHP:**

```
 vraag of Wens: 
 '.$message.'



|---------End Message----------|'; 

$check = $_POST['emailmarketing']; 
if ($check==false)
{
 echo "Error Please <a href='terms.php'>try again</a>"; 
}
else
{   
    echo "thank you for your request we will contact you asap."; 
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
?>
```

**Or if you want to validate via javascript:**

Add this to the `evalid` function:

```
var checkBox=document.contact_form.emailmarketing

if (checkBox.value==false){
    alert("Please accept the terms");
    checkBox.focus()
    return false
}
```

Comment: Someone with javascript turned off will still be able to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks micro.pravi, that worked great, but I now Im getting that message "thank you for your request we will contact you asap" twice one after another when the form is sent.

Comment: @user2486863 It should not come twice. you must be getting a text on the php page. not an `alert` if you meant.

Comment: I think I sorted that out, I didnt remove the previous part of the code, now I did and it works well! I have one more question, the link to this form will be placed in an invoice(word document) would it be possible to place some code in that link so it will extract for example the invoice number or name of the client from that word document and when the checkbox is ticked and email is send, the email will have that extracted part in the message, so it will tell me who accepted the terms?

Comment: I am sorry but you can not extract from word document in this way.

Comment: You can do this with notepad but with word, i am not familiar

Answer (score 2):

You must check if the chekbox checked.

Change

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    ...
```

to

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['emailmarketing'] == 'emailmarketing') {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add one more condition into javascript function evalid that is

```
if document.getElementById('emailmarketing').value==false {

    alert("you must accept terms of trade");
    return false;

}
```

While submitting the form it will check for that checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the user for submitting the form (if unchecked) by using `jquery`

```
if($('#your_checkbox_id').attr('checked')) {
       return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
```